# Safe character encoding string - Guns N' Roses – Sweet Child O’ Mine

Tags: php, html, utf-8

On my personal website http://www.matthewfedak.co.uk - pull in the last 6 songs I have listened to that were tracked via my last.fm profile. I store these in a db and then just loop through and display the results on the homepage.

I have noticed today though that tack Guns N' Roses – Sweet Child O’ Mine is not being encoded properly. The first 2 apostrophes are fine but the third one is causing an issue. My site is utf-8 character encoded on the front end the same as my last.fm profile page here http://www.last.fm/user/matthewfedak which is also utf-8 encoded so I do not understand why on my site the problem is occurring.

The song title is fine in my database its just on the front end it displays weird.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you passed the encoded bytes to an HTML entity encoder: the HTML reads `&acirc;��`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source of your website, it seems that you have passed the encoded UTF-8 string through an HTML entity encoder that doesn't understand UTF-8 at some point:

```
<a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Guns+N%27+Roses/_/Sweet+Child+O%E2%80%99+Mine" title="Guns N' Roses- Sweet Child O&acirc;�� Mine" target="_blank" rel="external nofollow">
```

Observe that `&acirc;` is the HTML entity for U+00E2, the first character of the UTF-8 sequence (E2 80 99).

Answer (score 1):

Hey Matthew you probably want to be doing it like

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Is that sorting it for you?

Comment: From php.net: Like htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards. Although this argument is technically optional, you are highly encouraged to specify the correct value for your code.